# Working with array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem when i'm working with array of objects in Javascript.

The problem: input

```
    [
    {  
        "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
        "workId": "554a9e4fa36f794b31000024"
    }, 
    {
        "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
        "workId": "554d3ffbcc477a7110000003"
    },
    {
        "artistName": "Kristin",
        "workId": "557a4kfbcc5e2a7110000223"
    }
    ]
```

And output should be:

```
    [
    {
        "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
        "workId"    : ["554a9e4fa36f794b31000024", "554d3ffbcc477a7110000003"]
    },
    {
        "artistName": "Kristin",
        "workId": ["557a4kfbcc5e2a7110000223"]
    }
    ]
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: And where did you get stuck? What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: 1. How is it being generated currently that is giving you the unexpected output? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: you should probably use an object instead of an array to store key:value pairs... `{Kristin: ["12343"], "NgaNguyen Duy": [123,456] }`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: you use "NgaNguyen Duy"  two times as key

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do aggregate :

var t =  [
    {  
        "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
        "workId": "554a9e4fa36f794b31000024"
    }, 
    {
        "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
        "workId": "554d3ffbcc477a7110000003"
    },
    {
        "artistName": "Kristin",
        "workId": "557a4kfbcc5e2a7110000223"
    }
    ];


var u = {};
var res = [];

t.forEach(function(item){
    if(!u[item.artistName]){        
         u[item.artistName] = [];  
    }
    u[item.artistName].push(item.workId);

});

for(var key in u){
    res.push({'artistName':key,'workId':u[key]});
}

console.log(res);


https://jsfiddle.net/Lgbcxorj/
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking to merge "workId"'s for like-named entries?:

```
var artists_in =     [
{  
    "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
    "workId": "554a9e4fa36f794b31000024"
}, 
{
    "artistName": "NgaNguyen Duy",
    "workId": "554d3ffbcc477a7110000003"
},
{
    "artistName": "Kristin",
    "workId": "557a4kfbcc5e2a7110000223"
}
]

var artists_out = {}
for (i = 0; i < artists_in.length; i++)
{
  artistKey = artists_in[i]["artistName"];
  if(artists_out[artistKey] == null)
  {
    artists_out[artistKey] = { "artistName": artistKey, "workId": [artists_in[i]["workId"]] };
  }
  else
  {
    artists_out[artistKey]["workId"].push(artists_in[i]["workId"]);
  }
}

console.log(artists_out);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hv9dtd8w/4/